# List Items are not getting displayed from first when the number of items in the list exceeds the screen height

Tags: javascript, css, html

We need to play video and when user presses key 'm', we need to divide the screen in to 2 halves vertically. One half should display just a text 'DVR' and other half should display a list and with 30 list items (This number is just for testing purpose. Originally we will be getting the number from server). Every list item will contain an image and some text. When we display the menu, Always list items should be visible from first and first item should be having focus. When we press key down, the focus should be shifted to second item ... Below is the code.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>VOD</title>
        <script src='lib/hls.js'></script>
        <script src='js/index.js'></script>
        <style>
            html, body
            {
                height:100%;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #vid
            {
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                z-index: -1;
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            #mid {
                display: flex;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                justify-content: stretch;
                flex-flow: row nowrap;
                z-index: 2;
            }

            #mid.hidden {
                display: none;
            }

            #mid1, #mid2 {
                display: flex;
                flex: 1;
                align-items: center;
            }

            #mid1 {
                justify-content: center;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
            }

            #mid2 {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
            }

            #ulid {
                list-style-type: none;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                border: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .list-item {
                width: 100%;
                height: 150px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                display:flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: flex-start;
            }

            li:focus {
                background-color: lightslategray;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id='vid' src='textMotion.mp4' autoplay loop></video>
        <div id='mid' class='hidden'>
            <div id="mid1">
                <h1>DVR</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="mid2">
                <ol id='ulid'></ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var foc_list_index = 0;

function processListEvent(event) {
    console.log('list Event : ' + event.keyCode + 'focused li ' + foc_list_index);

    let keyCode = event.keyCode;

    // Down
    if(keyCode == 40) {
        foc_list_index ++;
        document.getElementById('li' + foc_list_index).focus();
    }

    // Up
    if(keyCode == 38) {
        if(foc_list_index == 0) {
            console.log('Ignoring key up as we are already at first list index');
            return;
        }

        foc_list_index --;
        document.getElementById('li' + foc_list_index).focus();
    }
}

function displayMenu() {

    let mid = document.getElementById('mid');

    // If already menu is visible, hide it
    if(mid.classList.contains('hidden') == false) {
        mid.classList.toggle('hidden');
        let ulid = document.getElementById('ulid');
        while(ulid.firstChild) {
            ulid.removeChild(ulid.firstChild);
        }
        return;
    }

    let ulid = document.getElementById('ulid');

    for(let index = 0; index < 30; index ++) {
        let lItem = document.createElement('li');
        lItem.classList.add('list-item');
        lItem.setAttribute('id', 'li' + index);
        lItem.setAttribute('tabindex', index);
        lItem.addEventListener('keydown', processListEvent, false);

        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = 'img/TNT.png';

        lItem.appendChild(img);

        lItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Showing ID : ' + index));
        ulid.appendChild(lItem);
    }

    mid.classList.toggle("hidden");
    document.getElementById('li0').focus();
    foc_list_index = 0;
}

function processKeyPress(e) {
    console.log('received keyEvent : ' + e.keyCode);
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;

    let mid = document.getElementById('mid');

    // Menu button or key 'm'
    if((keyCode == 77) || (keyCode == 462)) {
        displayMenu();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', processKeyPress);
```

This code is working fine except below issues.

1) When user presses 'm', menu is getting displayed and second half is displaying from the list item 12. Even though list items from 0 to 29 are present, it is getting displayed from list item 12. But it should display from list item 0. I found out the reason for this issue. This is because I am keeping 'align-items: center;' for both mid1 and mid2 to keep the text on the first screen and to keep the list on the second screen should be centered vertically. If I remove 'align-items: center;' for mid2, the list is displaying properly but when list has very few items like 3 (instead of 30), the list is not getting displayed vertically centered. Not sure how to fix this issue.

2) When I do key down, once the focus crosses the the visible list item, the left half of the screen is also getting moved which shouldn't be moved.

Screen shot for first issue (list items should be displayed from 0 when user selects 'm')

[image]

Screen shot for the issue if I remove 'align-items: center;' for mid2 and the list has 3 items (instead of 30). List should be centered vertically.

[image]

Screen shot for the second issue (the left half of the screen is getting moved which shouldn't be moved when focus crosses the the visible list item by doing key down)

[image]

Can any one please help me to fix these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you use `justify-content:flex-start` (or `baseline`) that this will solve the number issue (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/ee791zLc/)) If you include a height for the `img`, this will display the items more clearly than in the first fiddle (see [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/2z69p2m1/)) , however it affects the width. The left hand video doesn't move in these fiddles, only the h1.  I was unclear on this. You could include it in the video div? (but perhaps you want it as an overlay? ..)

Anyway, it's a start.. hope this helps..